AMOVA in Rstudio with haploid data
I have haplotype data from mitochondrial DNA, which is divided into different countries and different cities within the countries. I would like to do an AMOVA (analysis of molecular variance), to see if there is any significant differences between the countries or cities. Because I am working with molecular data (haplotypes) I want to see if there are signifcant differences based on the DNA sequences
I have been doing some experimenting with the "poppr" package in Rstudio, however I am not sure if this package is appropriate because you have to transform your data into genclone object. So my question is, if it is possible to do an AMOVA with haploid data using the "poppr" package, or if there is another method that is more suitable for haploid data.

You can use vegan or adegenet to run AMOVA on haploid data and compare it with poppr results. I do not see why converting the input to genclone object would be a problem.
nic

Hi, thanks for your response. The reason why I don't want to convert it to a genclone object is because genclose is used for loci and SNPs, whereas I am working with haplotype, so sequence data.
